# cascading calls of same function java

Tags: java, spring-boot

i was working with sparkSession object in java and encountered a code snippet like this

```
SparkSession.builder()
.appnamme("some name")
.config(..,..)
.config(..,..)
.config(..,..)
.getOrCreate();
```

i am interested in implementing something like the cascading .config() calls ,
how can I recreate this method type in java?

for eg a cascading call which would simply add some string to a list

Comment: each of those methods return the object back.

Comment: Like @ChengThao says, just declare the return type to be the class itself, and end the method with `return this;`